# android java layout + source code confusion

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout

I'm a new to android programming. I'm having issues with the layout in my activity. My menu appears like this:

[image]

and I've done all the layout work directly through the source code:

```
enterNameTxt.setText("Enter User Name");
enterNameTxt.setY(200);
enterNameTxt.setX(-600);

userNameTxt.setY(300);
userNameTxt.setX(100);
userNameTxt.setWidth(200);

enterSpeedTxt.setText("Enter Speed");
enterSpeedTxt.setX(-500);
enterSpeedTxt.setY(100);

userSpeedTxt.setX(-400);
userSpeedTxt.setY(700);
userSpeedTxt.setWidth(200);

configButton.setWidth(400);
configButton.setText("Back to Game");
configButton.setY(1000);
```

and as you can see the speed option doesn't even show up on the screen. And I keep playing with setX, setY, setWidth options but it keeps getting messy.

Is it wrong to do the layout directly through the source code?

I have a two activities but only a layout xml file for one of them. Am I supposed to create another xml file in res/layout section for the menu activity?

I just don't understand when I use the source code and when I should use the layout...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a seperate XML layout file for each activity. Define as much as possible in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it wrong to do the layout directly through the source code?

No it's not. But you are strongly advised to use `xml` layout because it gives you a visual presentation of what you are trying before runtime.

> I have a two activities but only a layout xml file for one of them. Am I supposed to create another xml file in res/layout section for the menu activity?

Yes. You have to create an xml file for every activity in your app.

> I just don't understand when I use the source code and when I should use the layout...

You should use `xml` as much as you can. You should only use Java code to set layout attributes when it has to change at runtime. E.g populating a `ListView` with text from an database or a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in you java file

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout_params =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);  
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box_params =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);  
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btn_params =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(120, 40);  
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    EditText et1 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    et1.setHint("Enter User name");
    EditText et2 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    et2.setHint("Enter speed");
    Button btn= new Button(MainActivity.this);
    btn.setText("Back to Game");
    btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    ll.addView(et1, box_params);
    ll.addView(et2, box_params);
    ll.addView(btn, btn_params);
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    rl.addView(ll,layout_params );
}
```

}

You will get required output but it is prefer to use xml file until you don't need dynamic changes in your UI. It is easy to maintain code and design screens using xml files and if there is no need of large dynamic changes you should use xml files. Through Xml files you can check you code on different resolution through graphical representation of code. You can create a xml file in layout folder and can link it to your activity. It is easy, time saving and provide you more accurate designs... :) Please check screen shot for dynamic creation of your required design.

[image]

Happy Coding !!!